# In Slack, can I use a bot's message text in an outgoing webhook?

Tags: slack-api, dockerhub, slack

I've setup an outgoing webhook for my Slack team that listens to all messages on a channel and parses them for metadata that I might use to trigger further actions. It all works fine except for messages from bots.

I've added the [travis-ci](https://slack.com/apps/A0F81FP4N-travis-ci) integration which works great but when the webhook posts that bot's message data to my external endpoint the `text` field is empty.  Here's an example dump of the post data I'm getting back in that case:

```
Array
(
    [token] => xxx
    [team_id] => xxx
    [team_domain] => xxx
    [service_id] => xxx
    [channel_id] => xxx
    [channel_name] => builds
    [timestamp] => 1468073807.000103
    [user_id] => USLACKBOT
    [user_name] => slackbot
    [text] =>                   <-- no text here...
    [bot_id] => xxx
    [bot_name] => 
)
```

So my question is, have I setup something wrong or missed a setting to allow that text to be included, is it a bug, or is that expected behavior? I don't see anything in [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) about it. The If the answer is I can't do anything to get the travis-ci bot's text, does anyone have any ideas on how to work with bot messages in an automated way?

The real problem I'm trying to solve is triggering deployments based on the travis-ci build status, but I haven't been successful because you can't customize the payload for webhooks in github or travis-ci (or slack) and I don't want to expose any authentication details in a deployment script for travis-ci to execute. And Slack seems like a very convenient intermediary that I can keep building off of, but I just started learning about the integrations.

I have not looked into encrypted environment variables in travis-ci yet because I'd like to manage this with webhooks and apis rather than adding an extra custom script in my repo unless that's not possible.

I have no problem with looking at another approach though, the "deployment" I'm trying to trigger is just a Docker Hub build.

Answer (score 0):

[Outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks)s are now deprecated and should no longer be used. And if I remember correctly its a know issues that they don't show bot messages.

Instead I would recommend to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). You can listen to all messages of a channel by subscribing to the [`message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message) event. That will include bot messages.